# Why can't you vote on a question once you have retracted your vote?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, vote-to-close

Once you have voted on a question, and then retracted your vote, you are unable to cast another vote, why is this? Because for instance I could VTC something as unclear, but then when they update it I retract the vote, and as they say more, I realise it is a duplicate of another question, why am I then not able to VTC again? Is this because it could be abused? Or for some other reason? If it's to prevent abuse, measures could be put in place to prevent this, like not being able to VTC on a question again for a set period of time after you have retracted your vote.

Comment: To prevent abuse. And to stop the windows file transfer dialog from voting to close questions.

Comment: @Seth: "the windows file transfer dialog"?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/612/